# Split List<String> into small concatenated List<String> java 8 parallel execution

Tags: java, java-stream

So I have 2000 records of company names. I could like to take first 50 names and concatenate it and save as a string and then append it to a new List .

Does anyone have any idea how can we achieve it using java8 ?
Can this be done using parallelstream api?

Currently I’m iteration over 2k records and appending the data to a string builder . Meanwhile after every 50th count I’m creating a new String builder  . After every 50 record I add the string builder content to a list. Finally i get list With all the data.

Example: a1@ , a2 till a2000

Final output: LiSt of String with
1st entry —> concatenation of a1 to a50,
2nd entry —> concatenation of a51 to a100

Code:

```
List<String> bulkEmails ; //Fetched from DB
int count = 50; 

List<String> splitEmails = new ArrayList<>(); //Final output

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); // temp builder

for (String mail : bulkEmails) {
    builder.append(mail).append(",");
    count++;
    //append concatenated 50mails, appends to finalOutput and then resets the counter
    if (count == 50) {
        splitEmails.add(builder.toString());
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to have a string of 50 names? This sounds like an `XY` problem.

Comment: It's not clear, why do you think you need **parallel** streams for that ? And when you're saying *"achieve it using java8"* you mean that you're using JDK 8 or you refer to Stream API?

Comment: Also, if you're expecting to get feedback, then please, [*edit the question*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73587500/edit) and share the code you have.

Comment: @WJS I want the set of that spilt data for further processing using multithreading

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko currently I’m using for loop and string builder. I want to know if the process can be automated using java8 or some sort of threading mechanism..

Comment: @NewBee Sorry but you didn't address neither of my questions in your reply, if  you mind I want to kindly ask to reread my messages. It's still unclear what do you refer to while saying Java 8, a language version, or particular features?

Comment: @NewBee There are two reasons why I was asking you to share your code: **1.** it always brings value to the question, **2.** it highly advisable for question where you expect to see the code in the answers, every question SO is expected to demonstrate a research effort (see more information in the Help Center).

Comment: @NewBee Lastly `2K` elements isn't a really massive data that requires concurrent processing. And more importantly, this task **isn't parallelizable**. Try to model the process of splitting the data into chucks that would be processed by different threads, and joining the results on a paper, you'll see that there would be no performance gain due to the nature of the task.

Comment: In case if you want to see stream-based code. Firstly, you have to provide your **current code** and at least an **attempt** to implement it with streams. So, again, I advise you to [*improve your question*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73587500/edit).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko : I have pasted the code. Actually for every 50 concatenated mails I want to call a REST API to send emails.

Comment: Don’t post non-working pseudo code. Post the real code. And explain what’s wrong with it that you think you have to rewrite it.

Comment: @Holger : what is not working in that code? Also I’m not asking for someone to write a code and give me. I’ve clearly asked for a clean approach.

Comment: @NewBee 1) Trying to instantiate an interface of List 2) Stringbuilder using wrong case 3) invalid quotation marks 4) toString invoked with no brackets 5) Invalid use of wildcard

Comment: Letting all the errors in the code aside, if you have a working approach, why do you assume that it is not “a clean approach”?

Comment: @Holger , Michael : If you can not help me , please stay out of this post. Dont need your over smartness. Secondly even though I have a working code, I am looking for a nicer approach which could increase speed, consume less memory and be efficient. (i was looking for some multithreaded/ parallelstream / stream using groupingBy/ Queue ) approaches. Also I was expecting JUST AN APPROACH.

Comment: “*I am looking for a nicer approach which could increase speed, consume less memory and be efficient.*” Well, why don’t you ask about *that*, instead of what you have asked? An efficient solution has nothing to do with parallel streams at all. `final int chunkSize = 50; List<String> splitEmails = new ArrayList<>(); for(int ix1 = 0, ix2 = chunkSize; ix1 < bulkEmails.size(); ix1 = ix2, ix2 += chunkSize) splitEmails.add(String.join(", ", bulkEmails.subList(ix1, Math.min(ix2, bulkEmails.size()))));` That doesn’t mean that the `StringBuilder` based approach wasn’t clean.

Answer (score 0):

As I've said in the comments, `2K` isn't really a massive data.

And there's an issue with executing this task in parallel.

Let's imagine this task of splitting the data into groups of `50` elements is running in parallel somehow and the first worker thread is being assigned with a chunk of data containing `523` elements, the second - `518` elements, and so on. And none of these chunks is a product `50`. As a consequence of this, each thread would produce a partial result containing a group of size which differs from `50`.

Depending on how you want to deal with such cases, there are different approaches on how to implement this functionality:

- Join partial results as is. It implies that the final result would contain an **arbitrary number** of groups having size in range `[1,49]`. That is the simplest option to implement, and cheapest to execute. But, note that there could even the case when **every** resulting group is smaller than `50` be since you're not in control of the splitterator implementation (i.e. you can't dictate what would be large would be a chuck of data which particular thread would be assigned to work with). Regardless how strict/lenient your requirements are, that doesn't sound very nice.
- The second option requires reordering the elements. While joining partial results produced by each thread in parallel, we can merge the two last groups produced by every thread to ensure that there would be **only one** group at most that differs in size from `50` in the final result.
- If you're not OK with either joining partial results as is, or reordering the elements, that implies that this task isn't suitable for parallel execution because in case when the first thread produces a partial result containing a group of size smaller than `50` all the groups created by the second thread need to be rearranged. Which results in worse performance in parallel because of doing the same job twice.

The second thing we need to consider is that the operation of creating groups requires **maintaining a state**. Therefore, the right place for this transformation is inside a *collector*, where the stream is being consumed and *mutable container* of the collector gets updated.

Let's start with implementing a `Collector` which ignores the issue described above and joins partial results as is.

For that we can use static method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)).

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Deque<List<T>>> getGroupCollector(int groupSize) {
    
    return Collector.of(
        ArrayDeque::new,
        (Deque<List<T>> deque, T next) -> {
            if (deque.isEmpty() || deque.getLast().size() == groupSize) deque.add(new ArrayList<>());
            deque.getLast().add(next);
        },
        (left, right) -> {
            left.addAll(right);
            return left;
        }
    );
}
```

Now let's implement a `Collector` which merges the two last groups produced in different threads (option 2 in the list above):

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Deque<List<T>>> getGroupCollector(int groupSize) {
    
    return Collector.of(
        ArrayDeque::new,
        (Deque<List<T>> deque, T next) -> {
            if (deque.isEmpty() || deque.getLast().size() == groupSize) deque.add(new ArrayList<>());
            deque.getLast().add(next);
        },
        (left, right) -> {
            if (left.peekLast().size() < groupSize) {
                List<T> leftLast = left.pollLast();
                List<T> rightLast = right.peekLast();
                int llSize = leftLast.size();
                int rlSize = rightLast.size();
                if (rlSize + llSize <= groupSize) {
                    rightLast.addAll(leftLast);
                } else {
                    rightLast.addAll(leftLast.subList(0, groupSize - rlSize));
                    right.add(new ArrayList<>(leftLast.subList(groupSize - rlSize, llSize)));
                }
            }
            left.addAll(right);
            return left;
        }
    );
}
```

If you wish to implement a `Collector` which *combiner function* rearranges the partial results if needed (the very last option in the list), I'm leaving it to the OP/reader as an exercise.

Now let's use the collector defined above (the latest). Let's consider a stream of single-letter strings representing the characters of the English alphabet, and let's group size would be `5`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> groups = IntStream.rangeClosed('A', 'Z')
        .mapToObj(ch -> String.valueOf((char) ch))
        .collect(getGroupCollector(5))
        .stream()
        .map(group -> String.join(",", group))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    groups.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*Output:*

```
A,B,C,D,E
F,G,H,I,J
K,L,M,N,O
P,Q,R,S,T
U,V,W,X,Y
Z
```

That's the sequential result. If you switch, the stream from sequential to parallel the contents of the groups would probably change, but the *sizes would not be affected*.

Also note that since there are effectively two independent streams chained together, you need to apply `parrallel()` twice to make the whole thing working in parallel.